# Dark Mode: NSColor.colorNamed doesn't return the right color in certain methods

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-darkmode

colorNamed generally works for me, however, I am trying to call it inside `NSTableViewRow.drawSeparatorInRect:`, and it always return the color in the light appearance, even if the system is in Dark Mode.

`- (void)drawSeparatorInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
   [[NSColor colorNamed:@"ColorTransactionsGridLine"] set];
   ...
}`

I can't figure out why `colorNamed` doesn't work in this case. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this before your drawing code:

```
 NSAppearance.currentAppearance = self.effectiveAppearance;
```

Or, as a diagnostic measure, set a breakpoint in your drawing code and check the status of these properties in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out. Turns out the parent view has appearance hard coded, so the subview inherit that appearance rather than the system's. After changing appearance to "inherit" in the parent view(s), `colorNamed` returns the right color.